# Programmatically Remove outlook signature

Tags: outlook

how to remove programmatically an Outlook signature on a client?

We have set in Exchange server a default signature. What happens is that a user has a
personal signature, the signature is doubled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not delete the files where the signature is stored?